# Where does the PHP interpreter actually process PHP that is written by us?

Tags: php

I am a little interested in editing the real PHP source code for... Playing?
Anyways, does anyone know where does the PHP compiler actually parse/compile the PHP code? I just simply want it to show the code before it is interpreted (What is it now? Compiled?). I don't really understand the process, so tell me if I am wrong?

Comment: [The PHP internals book](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/) would be a great place for you to start.

Comment: http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/117-PHP-compiler-performance.html

Comment: [Explanation from one of PHP's core developers](http://www.slideshare.net/jpauli/quick-tour-of-php-from-inside)

Comment: I use [lxr.php.net](http://lxr.php.net/) to browse the code. There are links to git repositories as well. The code parsing isn't done at one place, and the best way is to follow the C code and use lxr to find the interesting parts (lexer code, vm code etc).

Comment: @Mjh About where can I start?

Comment: @Legoboy0215 - under `Zend/`. You'll find the most relevant code there, from opcodes (`zend_vm_opcodes.c` and `zend_vm_opcodes.h`), hash table implementation, VM implementation etc. I don't know where the actual lexer is, are you after lexical analyzer / tokenizer or after the code that executes opcodes? If I'm recalling correctly, PHP uses [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) for parsing. However, I believe there are some guys from PHP internals present here so hopefully they'll jump in with correct anser.